# Stream.listen survives full restart of flutter on web

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, websocket, flutter-web

Stream.listen() seems to survive a full restart on web and sometimes on mobile as well.
`main.dart`

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:web_socket_channel/web_socket_channel.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:math';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => MaterialApp(home: MyHomePage());
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  var test = 0;
  late int randomInt;
  var random = Random();
  var uri = Uri.parse('wss://ws-feed-public.sandbox.pro.coinbase.com');
  late WebSocketChannel channel;
  String request = json.encode({
    "type": "subscribe",
    "product_ids": ["BTC-USD"],
    "channels": ["heartbeat"],
  });

  @override
  void initState() {
    randomInt = random.nextInt(1000);
    channel = WebSocketChannel.connect(uri);
    channel.sink.add(request);
    channel.stream.listen((event) {
      print('$randomInt: $test');
      test = test + 1;
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Container();
}
```

`pubspec.yaml`

```yaml
name: echowebsocket
description: A new Flutter project.

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  web_socket_channel: ^2.1.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

When I run the above code in flutter web and I do a hot restart (the green play button in android studio) the stream .listen() function survives the restart leaving two listening functions running.
An example output after running from cold (Chrome closed):

```
This application is not configured to build on the web.
To add web support to a project, run `flutter create .`.
Launching lib/main.dart on Chrome in debug mode...
Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...
This app is linked to the debug service: ws://127.0.0.1:56738/yLBcQjxMep4=/ws
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:56738/yLBcQjxMep4=/ws

 Running with sound null safety 
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:56738/yLBcQjxMep4=/ws
582: 0
582: 1
582: 2
582: 3
582: 4
582: 5
582: 6
582: 7
582: 8
```

Then after a hot restart:

```
Performing hot restart...
Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...
582: 30
Restarted application in 155ms.
876: 0
876: 1
582: 31
876: 2
582: 32
876: 3
582: 33
582: 34
876: 4
582: 35
876: 5
582: 36
876: 6
582: 37
876: 7
876: 8
```

As you can see there are now two listen functions being executed. I was under the impression that no state is supposed to survive a hot restart. I have sometimes been able to recreate this problem on emulators but it seems to work every time on web. Here is the output of flutter doctor:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.2, on macOS 11.6 20G165 darwin-x64, locale en)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    ✗ cmdline-tools component is missing
      Run `path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more details.
    ✗ Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup for more details.
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Answer (score -1):

What you are experiencing is a memory/resource leak. You need to override close the `WebSocketChannel` when you are done.

```
@override
void dispose() {
  channel.sink.close();
  super.dispose();
}
```

**Update**
The problem is due to how hot restart works on Chrome. Please check out this [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/69949) on GitHub.

Comment: When I add that code I get the same behavior. It seems that dispose() doesn't get called when you do a hot restart. But I thought it shouldn't matter because everything gets wiped out when you do a hot restart.

Comment: A hot restart cannot simply wipe everything. You have to ensure that you release resources as needed. However, `dispose()` is called when you do a hot restart, and this is where you should generally release resources. I just tried your code adding nothing but my suggestion and it works. You may be seeing remnants from previous web socket channels still in your memory. As a memory leak, you will not be able to get rid of them via your code and restarts. Try power cycling the device.

Comment: I restarted my whole computer and then tried it again and still go the same behavior. Were you trying it in chrome?

Comment: My apologies, I did not see that the issue was on Chrome. The problem is indeed how hot reload works on Chrome. It immediately kills the page, and therefore app, without out disposing resources. Please check out this [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/69949) on GitHub. There are a couple of workarounds discussed in that thread that you may wish to employ. Still, be sure to always close your streams in `dispose` though.

Comment: Ah there it is. Thanks for the help.